# How to use Matlab xunit without setting Matlab application path

Tags: matlab, xunit

As far as we can see, to use a library in Matlab it is necessary to add its path to the global Matlab application path e.g. to use the xunit unit testing library, its path must be added to the global path through the user interface. The problems with this are:

- Each developer must set the dependency paths correctly on their machine, test machines and build machines etc. to be able to run the code correctly
- We cannot set the paths for each developer centrally so when dependencies change, we must issue instructions for individuals to manually change their configuration
- If different projects use incompatible dependencies then the path must be reconfigured between changing projects

For C++\C#\Java etc. projects, it is possible to refer to libraries with relative paths from within the project and not require changes to global environment variables.

How can we achieve this with Matlab?

Comment: Just FYI, if the issue you're facing is specifically to do with a unit testing framework rather than general project-based path management, you should take a look at the just-released version 2013a of MATLAB. It includes a built-in unit testing framework (no need for path management), much more powerful and flexible than xUnit. I haven't tried it out much yet, but it looks awesome.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `addpath` and `rmpath` commands to manually edit MATLAB's Path.  Paths added via these two commands can be relative paths.

Comment: Thanks - is there a recommended practice for how to use these to switch between project specific environments?

Comment: That I can't help you with.  One suggestion might be to have a project  specific init/uninit scripts that sets/remove the project specific paths and have your code call these functions.

Comment: +1 for `addpath` and `rmpath`. Also take a look at [`onCleanUp`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/oncleanup.html) which you can use in combination with `rmpath` to make sure your path setting is always reverted regardless of any exceptions, etc.